# iperf error: connect failed: no route to host

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, iperf

I have installed same version of iperf (2.0.5) on 2 different ubuntu systems.
But when i execute command `iperf -s -p 45678` on one system and `iperf -c 172.18.41.17 -p 458 -t 10` on another system. It gives me error "connect failed: No route to host".

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: One system is working as server but the same system is not working as client.

Comment: what is the idle timeout of iperf client before it decides no route to host if the client didnt get any reply from server.?

Answer (score 8):

sometimes, the firewall service will prevent the tcp connection initiation, try by disabling the firewall service in client and server "service firewalld stop

Comment: "no route to host" is not a TCP level issue

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. The error message is particularly confusing because it is not a routing issue. `route -n` showed expected entries, I could ping, etc. but `iptables` was filtering traffic on the server. When I cleared its rules and set all policies to ACCEPT this error message went away. (I doubt I'd have found this, but when I tried reversing the roles of the 2 machines it works, and the main difference was that one was running CentOS with `firewalld` enabled while the other was running Ubuntu without a firewall enabled.)

Answer (score 2):

by default iperf uses its ipv6 
run on the server

```
iperf -s -p -4 45678
```

on the client run

```
iperf -c 172.18.41.17 -p 458 -t 10 -4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port. I'm having this issue but when I try other ports, it is working. I'd like to know the reason however.

Also server and client port should be the same

Comment: Changing the port number did not resolve this problem for me nor did adding `-4` to force IPv4.

Comment: I had this 'no route to host' problem in my automation. The problem turned out that,  I was starting the client too soon. I needed to wait a few more seconds after starting the server before starting the client. Also you should be able to ping the address too. if you can't ping it then then you are missing some route...

Answer (score 0):

If the link delay in the network is greater than tcp connection timeout value. Then, this might happen. Because the SYN packet wont get ACK within the timeout value. Therefore iperf client will out Connection failed: No route to host

Answer (score -1):

netstat -rn on the client to might be helpful.  The client is complaining that it doesn't have have a route and it's routing tables can help diagnose why.

Answer (score -1):

```
iperf -s -p 45678
```

Here you started server on port no. 45678. and

```
iperf -c 172.18.41.17 -p 458 -t 10
```

For client also you should use the same port no. you are using here port no. 458. make it same as server and test. the error might because of the mismatched port no.